# Before training the CNN network score on the testing data

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I have a simple binary image classification CNN network. Below is the code

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same',
                     kernel_initializer=gabor_init, input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=gabor_init))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Dense(2,input_dim=128,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
trainX,testX,trainY,testY=train_test_split(Xdata,Ytarget,test_size=.3)

history=model.fit(trainX,trainY,epochs=70,batch_size = 64, 
                         verbose = 1,validation_split=.3)

print(model.evaluate(testX,testY))
```

Here I am training the model then validating the model. My question is

I want to check the model on the test data before training; as I am using the Gabor Kernel Initializer, I want to see how this filter works before training. In that case, do I need to add `model.fit()? I am little confused.

Any suggestion or modification for the last part of the code so the model can be tested on test data before training?

Comment: Did you try `model.predict()` before training? What was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have defined your model in *keras*, you are only required to compile it using the `model.compile()` in order to be able to invoke predictions on the initial untrained weights. `model.fit()` only updates the weights as the model is trained and does not contribute to any configuration setup.